# Excel Select Range Copy Paste issue

Tags: excel, copy, formula, paste

I have an Excel file where there are 2 sheets: "Upload sheet" and "TemplateClauses" . In the worksheet "Upload sheet" there are formulas that if met they report a value, if not an empty cell.

How can i select the range of cells with values only (beginning from cell B4 until column Z and ignoring the empty ones which contain a formula) copies them and paste them into the sheet "TemplateClauses" as of cell B9?

Comment: Use a filter, copy/paste?

Comment: i was actually looking for a macro that selects the cells with values only and not the cells with formula inside that are empty because there are no values from the source

Answer (score 0):

copy the range of cells, hit alt+h+v+v, then re-paste because they are now values

Comment: i was actually looking for a macro that selects the cells with values only and not the cells with formula inside that are empty because there are no values from the source

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/7/21/selecting-non-blank-cells

Comment: follows the code i am using however it is selecting also cells with formulas where the value is empty cells...:

Sub PasteSpecial_Example5()

Workbooks("Template_ChargementClausesAPriori_.xls").Worksheets("Upload sheet").Range("B4:Z5004").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Workbooks.Open "G:\Global Sales\Accounts\Robbert-Jan Baas\2.PFIZER\Pfizer offer Renewal 2020-2023\Pfizer\5000 loadingSimulation.xls"
Workbooks("5000 loadingSimulations.xls").Worksheets("TemplateClauses").Range("B9:Z15009").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


End Sub